# Export grid data to a CSV file and save it with extension .csv by just using Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found several code that helps me generate a CSV file. But i am not able to save it with an extension of .csv

I am using the following code to generate a csv file, but i need to save the file with .csv as extension

```
var ExportToCSV= function (gridData, fileName, humanize, ignore){

           var csv = '',
           data = [],
        ignore = [];

                                                                         if (!ignore) {
        ignore = [];
    }

    //ignore added datasource properties       
    var commonIgnore = ["_events", "idField", "_defaultId", "constructor", "init", "get",
        "_set", "wrap", "bind", "one", "first", "trigger",
        "unbind", "uid", "dirty", "parent"];
    ignore = $.merge($.merge([], ignore), commonIgnore);

     var data= gridData._data;



    //add the header row
    if (data.length > 0) {
        for (var col in data[0]) {
            //do not include inherited properties
            if (!data[0].hasOwnProperty(col) || ($.inArray(col, ignore) > -1)) {
                continue;
            }

            if (humanize) {
                col = col.split('_').join(' ').replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1');
            }

            col = col.replace(/"/g, '""');
            csv += '"' + col + '"';
            if (col != data[0].length - 1) {
                csv += ",";
            }
        }
        csv += "\n";
    }

    //add each row of data
    for (var row in data) {
        for (var col in data[row]) {
            //do not include inherited properties
            if (!data[row].hasOwnProperty(col) || ($.inArray(col, ignore) > -1)) {
                continue;
            }

            var value = data[row][col];
            if (value === null) {
                value = "";
            } else if (value instanceof Date) {
                value = kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(value),"dd/MM/yyyy");
            } else {
                value = value.toString();
            }

            value = value.replace(/"/g, '""');
            csv += '"' + value + '"';
            if (col != data[row].length - 1) {
                csv += ",";
            }
        }
        csv += "\n";
    }

    //TODO replace with downloadify so we can get proper file naming
    window.open("data:application/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(csv));
```

};

There are many ways using server-side code like php, asp.net, java to resolve the issue. But can anybody help me achieve the same by just using client-side scripting i.e using Javascript/JQuery.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this excellent blog post for Chrome (and FF, haven't tested it yet though):
http://hackworthy.blogspot.co.nz/2012/05/savedownload-data-generated-in.html

I'm still searching for a working method on IE9 (ActiveX and execCommand() are not working for me). Last resort: Flash, heaps of plugins (Downloadify, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Because a browser is sandboxed, you wont be able to save the .csv  - however you could send it to the server, or to Dropbox or similar using an api, then provide the user with a link to download the file.